What's the word おしきた?

What exactly is the world おしきた used here? The character propose to make a chat room for the first year and they all agree.

Apparently it means よしきた！ but I've never seen it written that way.

おし is a variant of よし, which expresses positive acknowledgement (similar to "alright!", "got it!", "leave it to me!").
おし sounds more 豪快 (rough, strong) and 頼もしい (reliable, senior) compared to よし, and as far as I understand it's a new creative invention (like よっしゃー or うっしゃー).
In this example, you can see the first speaker uses 敬語, to which the second speaker replies in タメ口. So the intended nuance is, the second speaker is a 頼もしい先輩 who is readily (enthusiastically) backing up the first speaker.
